# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) flutte jsonr error response.body

Tags: json, flutter, firebase

json error
I checked and tried using toStrings().replaceAll("\n","")
And I also with only .toStrings()

post request

```
String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
Response response = await post(
                    uri,
                    headers: headers,
                    body: jsonBody,
                    encoding: encoding,
                  );       
Map valueMap = jsonDecode(response.body.toString().replaceAll("\n",""));
print(valueMap);
Map bodydata = valueMap['body'];
print(bodydata);
```

error:

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
    E/flutter ( 5352): <html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-...
```

Comment: Can you provide us what the body of your response should look like please

Comment: try printing `response.body` before you assign that `valueMap`. you will most likely find that it's not json

Comment: <html><head>
I/flutter ( 5352): <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
I/flutter ( 5352): <title>403 Forbidden</title>
I/flutter ( 5352): </head>
I/flutter ( 5352): <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
I/flutter ( 5352): <h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
I/flutter ( 5352): <h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/initiate</code> from this server.</h2>
I/flutter ( 5352): <h2></h2>
I/flutter ( 5352): </body></html>  this is showing

Comment: @Noobdeveloper that's an invalid status code response, you should've had 200 ( that's a valid status code response). 
Here I think this mean you do not have the right to post

Comment: whichever api you are using needs some form of authorization.

Comment: I am using firebase cloud functions

Comment: than it's seems the problem is from firebase and not flutter

Comment: ohh let me check if this is the case i will remove my question

Answer (score 0):

You don't verify you got a valid status code as a response.
You should try with something like this :

```dart
try{
  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
  var response = await post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody,
    encoding: encoding,
  );
  if (response.statusCode == Config.codeStatutHttpValide){
    var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    json.keys.forEach((key){
      print json[key];
    })
  }else{
    // not a valid response;
  }
} catch (e) {
 //could not post;
}
```